# Spring and Mock Framework integration

Tags: java, spring, frameworks, mocking

I am looking for the mock framework with good integration with spring. I've used mockito and it is good framework but spring integration via [springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home) IMHO, is not good. So, Could  you help me to chose good Mock Framework with good integration with Spring ? Thanks.

Comment: What should be the benefit of an spring integration for Mocking Frameworks. If you use mocking frameworks then your are doing small unit tests. There should be no spring context involved at all. Try to do this tests without spring, reduce its setup only to the classes you need.

Comment: It is interesting, but I've found solution for my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Sergii What is wrong with springockito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, I've just thought, I can create some mockito util class and use it via spring using `factory-method` without using springockito, Thanks to all problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with [Springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/springockito-annotations)? I like it for readabiltity i simplicity :)

```
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.*;
import org.kubek2k.springockito.annotations.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class, 
     loader = SpringockitoAnnotatedContextLoader.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class MainControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MainController mainController;

    @Autowired
    @ReplaceWithMock
    FooService fooService;

    @Test
    public void shouldGetBar() {
        //given
        given(fooService.result("foo")).willReturn("bar");

        //when
        Bar bar build = fooService.getBar("foo");

        //then
        assertThat(bar).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

Dependencies: `org.kubek2k:springockito-annotations:1.0.9`